Not Receiving Background Push Notification When Not Connected to Xcode
When I'm running my app in xcode, I can receive both background and alert notification regardless if the app is in the foreground or background.
When I disconnect the app from xcode and push the app to the background, I no longer receive background notifications. However, I receive alert notifications regardless if the app is in the foreground or background.
I created a production build, side loaded it with configurator with the same result.
I also changed the priority from 5 to 10 with no help.
